# Ajax dando erro 302

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou chamando a mesma funções JavaScript em formulários distintos na mesma página.

Quando chamo a função do primeiro formulário, é executado a função que executa um ajax normalmente.

Ao chamar a mesma função no segundo formulário, o ajax não é executado retornando o erro 302 Moved Temporarily.

Estou quebrando a cabeça para saber o porque do erro e até agora não consegui saber pois ao chamar a função no primeiro form funciona normalmente sem erro.

Problema está sendo executar na segunda chama no segundo form, e nesse segundo form chama a função da mesma forma do primeiro form.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/busca.php",
          type:"POST",
          data: { "valor": valor, "combo" : combo, "categoria" : categoriab, "estado" : estadob, "cidade" : cidadeb, "bairro" : bairrob, "etapa" : etapa},
          cache: false,
          success: function(response) {
              var resultado = JSON.parse(response);                    
              $("#"+resultado.etapa+"").html(resultado.combo);             
          },
          error: function() {
              alert(" Não foi possível completar a solicitação! ");
          },
          complete: function() {
              //direcionar para algum lugar                    
          } 
      });
```

Comment: Você pode compartilhar conosco os trechos relevantes dos forms e da function?

Comment: Provavelmente as páginas estão em diretórios diferentes. Já que você usa o mesmo _ajax_, um mapeia corretamente o caminho e o outro não.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e colocar o código do server-side

Comment: @rLinhares justamente o que disse. como fazer o mapeamento de forma correta para que possa funcionar adequadamente? um está na raiz, outro esta dentro de uma pasta, so funciona o que esta dentro da pasta. url: /arquivo.php , referencia so funciona para chamada do arquivo dentro da pasta, o que está fora da pasta está dando erro 302

Comment: @jbueno código postado